# Get the current MPMediaQuery, or MPMediaItemCollection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am trying to get the cover of the next song that is in the queue,

I've been using this

```
MPMediaQuery* assetQuery = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];

    NSArray *arrayOfItems = [assetQuery items];

    MPMediaItem *mediaItem = [arrayOfItems objectAtIndex:[musicPlayer indexOfNowPlayingItem] + 1];

    NSLog(@"%@", [mediaItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle]);
```

But today I found out that playlist has their own queues, and since I am using the iPodMusicPlayer,

if a user comes from the iPod Music Player playing a song that is in a playlist, to my app, he/she will see the wrong cover for the next item.

Is there a way to get the current MPMediaQuery, or MPMediaItemCollection?

like

> [musicPlayer nowPlayingSong];

maybe something like

> [musicPlayer nowPlayingQuery];

Please answer, thank you

Comment: Show the code where you are creating musicPlayer

Comment: musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];

Answer (score 0):

No. Apple do not provide access to the current playlist. This makes coding a decent replacement for the built in music player quite difficult.

I don't know why Apple would provide an SDK for the ipod music library but not give full access to the music controller.

It's quite buggy too.

Answer (score 0):

I.. kinda.. found a half-working workaround.

You can get access to playlists, and You can know current index of song in some playlist. Well probably, if song is really found in multiple playlists - more likely it's index will be different.. (but could be the same! )

So - I find out current songs persistentID:

```
_nowPlayingIPodItemPersistantID = [[[[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] nowPlayingItem]
        valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID] stringValue];
```

and then try to find out which playlist is active by comparing indexOfNowPlayingItem with each song, which's persistentID is equal to current songs persistentID:

```
    MPMediaQuery *query = [MPMediaQuery playlistsQuery];

    int count = 0;

    for (MPMediaPlaylist *playlist in [query collections])
    {
        if(_nowPlayingIPodCollectionItemPersistantID)
        {
            break;
        }

        count = 0;

        for(MPMediaItem *item in [playlist items])
        {
            if([[[item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID] stringValue] isEqualToString:_nowPlayingIPodItemPersistantID]
                && [[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] indexOfNowPlayingItem] == count)
            {
                _nowPlayingIPodCollectionItemPersistantID = [playlist valueForProperty: MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName];

                break;
            }

            count++;
        }
    }
    //===
```

Not perfect, but hey.. gotta do somethin, right?